# how to get item count from shopping cart in fly to cart jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, shopping-cart

I want to use a fly to cart jquery based plugin in a website, but problem is  getting  total number of items (item count) from cart and show on cart icon on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link for using fly to cart animation. to calculate the total items, say for example as per JS code given in the below link, on the click event of add-to-cart button, write a JS function passing the product object, if necessary to calculate price too . There you can update the total cart items in the Shopping cart.

```
var i =0;
 $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function () {
    i = i+1;
  });
alert('No. of item in cart : ' + i);
```

To show the cart image in all the pages, add the cart image in the anchor tag and place it in your header.

http://www.bypeople.com/fly-to-cart-effect/

From CSS you can get the cart image

http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/24/_cart.png